# How to find another end of ssh connection

Tags: ssh

I am connecting via SSH from host A to host B.

Is there a way to find connection source and re-connect from B to A  (for example to make scp from B to A) ?

Comment: What do you mean connection source? you can ssh B then when you are in ssh A. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Please give a more concrete example. Also, you are assuming that B is accessible, is that the case? If so, there's no need to reconnect. If you're connected to hostB, you can run `scp user@hostA:/path/to/file .` and that will copy from hostA to hostB.

Comment: it's the hostA which I want to find

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find the host you have connected from, use `w`:

```
$ who -m --ips
terdon   pts/4        2015-06-08 20:02 123.456.78.9
```

To get the IP only:

```
$ who -m --ips | awk '{print $NF}'
123.456.78.9
```

So, to scp from that host, you could do:

```
scp user@$(who -m --ips | awk '{print $NF}'):/remote/path /target/path
```

Answer (score 0):

This command shows established SSH connections and the target user:

```
LANG=C netstat  | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '/:22 |:ssh/ {sub(/:.*/,"",$5 ); system("who | grep \""$5"\"") }'
```

The user who established the connection can not be determined.

And only the host:

```
LANG=C netstat  | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '/:22 |:ssh/ {sub(/:.*/,"",$5 ); system("who | grep \""$5"\"") }' | awk '{gsub(/\(|\)/, "", $5); print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP address of the host you are connected from, you can use `grep` on the output of `ss`:

```bsh
ss -nt | grep -Po '^ESTAB.*?:22\s+\K[^:]+(?=:\d+)'
```

For example:

```bsh
$ ss -nt | grep -Po '^ESTAB.*?:22\s+\K[^:]+(?=:\d+)'
192.168.11.225
```

- `ss` stands for socket statistics, `ss -nt` will show the TCP sockets with numeric addresses as endpoints
- `grep -Po` will get only the matched portion from the line using PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions)
- `^ESTAB.*?:22\s+` will match `ESTAB` at start followed by the port `22` with anything in between, `\K` will discard the match
- `[^:]` will match our desired IP address
- The zero width positive look ahead pattern `(?=:\d+)` ensure that the IP address is followed by `:<port>`